# how to load value on popup onlink using mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

In my table based on my productID, I took the brandName. similarly based on productID I should take genericName it should be a load on the text field. I can able to load on drop-down list box but I cannot able to load on the text field.

[image: table]

[image: cllick]

**Script**

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#txtMedicineName").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("AutoComplete")',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.slice(0, 10000), function (item) {
                                return item;
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                    $("#hfCustomer").val(i.item.val);
                },
                minLength: 1,
            });

            function SelectName() {
                var id = jQuery('[id$=hfCustomer]').val();
                $.get("GenericName_Bind", { ProductID: id }, function (data) {
                    var v = "<option>--- Select Hospital Name ---</option>";
                    $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
                        v += "<option value=" + v1.Value + ">" + v1.Text + "</option>";I                        });
                    $("#txtGenericName").html(v);
                });
            }
        });
</script>
```

when i click on button genericName is loading in drop down. how to load in text field?

**Code**

```
    public JsonResult GenericName_Bind(string ProductID)
    {
        PrescriptionBind generic = new PrescriptionBind();
        DataSet ds = generic.Get_GenericName(ProductID);
        List<SelectListItem> statelist = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            statelist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["GenericName"].ToString(), Value = dr["GenericID"].ToString() });
        }
        return Json(statelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public DataSet Get_GenericName(string ProductID)
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from ProductMaster where ProductID=@ProductID", product);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", ProductID);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
```

[image: ee]

Comment: You're returning a list of `SelectListItem`s. Do you want to write them all in the same field? However, you can put a value in a textfield with eg.: `document.getElementById(id).value = somevalue` or with jQuery: `$('#id').val(somevalue)`

Comment: can you add full code please @Werner

Comment: `$('#id').val($.map(list, function(x) { return x.Value; }).join());` → Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/at8ts2a2/)

Comment: @Werner thank you sir